# Dynamically rendering mongodb document in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web, mern

Ok so I'm trying to make a MERN Stack application with crud functionality. Now unfortunately I have developed a lot of this application but now I'm having trouble integrating the backend in this. So far I have created the functionality to create blogs, save them in the database and render it in the frontend when a GET request is made. BuT to explain my problem, when I click on the read more of the blogs.jsx file, it is supposed to take me to a page where the entire content of the blog is visible (it is initially truncated in the blogs.jsx component). However when I do click on the read more nothing gets rendered. Not even the Navbar, And the errors are too difficult to understand. I tried asking to ChatGPT but it's solutions were not effective in giving a solution. Also I was tired to provide a lot of code to it so I'll do it here. I'm using React Router Dom to define my Routes.

So here are the Frontend codes.
This is the App.jsx

```
import './App.css'
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './pages/Home/Home'
import Compose from './pages/Compose/Compose'
import Blogs from './pages/Blogs/Blogs'
import About from './pages/About/About'
import Contacts from './pages/Contacts/Contacts'
import SingleBlog from './pages/SingleBlog/SingleBlog'

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>

        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/compose' element={<Compose />} />
        <Route path='/blogs' element={<Blogs />} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
        <Route path='/contact' element={<Contacts />} />
        <Route path='/blogs/:id' element={<SingleBlog />} />

      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is the blogs.jsx

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar/Navbar'
import './Blogs.css'

const Blogs = () => {

    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const fetchBlogs = async () => {

        try {
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/blogs')
            setBlogs(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchBlogs()
    }, []);

  return (
    <>
        <Navbar title="PEGASUS" op1="Compose" op2="About Us" op3="Contact Us" />

        {blogs.map(blog => (
            
        <div className="blog" key={blog._id}>

            <h1>{blog.blogTitle}</h1>
            <br />

            <main>
                <p>{blog.content.substring(0, 100)}...</p>
                <h3 onClick={() => navigate(`/blogs/${blog._id}`)} className='read-more'>Read More</h3>
            </main>

            <div className="author">
                <h4>- {blog.author}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        ))}

    </>
    )
}

export default Blogs;
```

This is where the blog is supposed to get dynamically rendered. On whichever's "Read More" the user clicks on it should take the user to this page where the that exact blog gets dynamically rendered with the route '/blogs/:id'. The blog._id should be the id in the parameters.

Now here are the Backend codes

server.js:

```
//IMPORTS
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

//ROUTE IMPORTS
import blogRoutes from './routes/blogRoutes.js'

//GENERAL CONSTANTS
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const db_URL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/blogDB";

//MIDDLEWARE
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

//ROUTES
app.use('/blogs', blogRoutes);

const connectDB = async url => {
    await mongoose
        .connect(url)
        .then(() => console.log("Database Connected"))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

//PORT LISTEN
app.listen(PORT, async () => {
    await connectDB(db_URL);
    console.log(`Server Started at port ${PORT}`);
})
```

blogRoutes.js:

```
import express from "express";
import { postBlog, getBlog, getSingleBlog } from "../controllers/blogController.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', postBlog);
router.get('/', getBlog);
router.get('/:id', getSingleBlog);

export default router;
```

blogController.js:

```
import blog from '../models/blogSchema.js';

export const postBlog = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const {title, content, author} = req.body;
        const newBlog = new blog ({
            blogTitle: title,
            content: content,
            author: author
        })

        await newBlog.save()
        res.send(newBlog);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        const error = true;
        res.send(error);
    }
}

export const getBlog = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const blogs = await blog.find({}).exec();
        res.send(blogs);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

export const getSingleBlog = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const singleblog = await blog.findOne({ _id: req.params.id})
        if(!singleblog) {
            var error = true;
            res.send(error);
        } else {
            res.send(singleblog);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Hopefully this much code is enough for y'all to give a solution. Please help me guys Integrating with axios is kinda difficult. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dynamic route, say `/blogs/[blogId].jsx`.

Point *Read More* button `onClick` to

Inside `[blogId].jsx`:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'

const ReadBlod() {
     const { blogId } = useParams();
     const [blogContent, setBlogContent] = useState({});

     useEffect(async () => {
         try {
             const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/blog/${blogId}`);
             setBlogContent(response.data);
         } catch (error) console.log(error);
     });

    if (blogContent == {}) {
        return <div></div> // Anything you want to display until loading is completed
    } else {
        return <div></div> // Main content
    }

    export default ReadBlog();
}
```

P.S.: You can create a seperate `isLoading` variable and set it to `true` after fetching is completed inside useEffect, it's a more professional approach.

Comment: Ok so you don't use the traditional way of making a dynamic url for example "/blogs/:blogid"? And can you please provide more context on how I can fetch that specific blog from the backend?

Comment: I think it shouldn't make a difference but I use `[route].js` only. You already have the `getSingleBlog` route in your backend. Just do an api call on that route, I've already put that code inside `useEffect`.

Comment: Ok it turns out I forgot to put curly braces in the blogs state variable. Putting that made it work like a charm. Appreciate your help man